# More on System Settings hang

Tags: 16.04, settings

Here's some more information on the System Settings hang problem I posted earlier ( [Ubuntu 16.04.2 hangs when open System Settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914484/ubuntu-16-04-2-hangs-when-open-system-settings) )

For the 1st time in the last half-dozen or so tries, it didn't hang indefinitely. I paid close attention to the clock and here is the information logged after the system hung for 11 seconds (22:02:46 - 22:02:57).

```
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.816238] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:29:pipe B] flip_done timed out
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.916862] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.916908] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 921 at /build/linux-hwe-7go7JY/linux-hwe-4.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_irq.c:1224 drm_wait_one_vblank+0x1b6/0x1c0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.916910] vblank wait timed out on crtc 1
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.916912] Modules linked in: nfsv3 nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss nfsv4 nfs lockd grace arc4 md4 nls_utf8 cifs fscache binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_si3054 snd_hda_codec_realtek hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq wl(POE) coretemp r852 snd_seq_device snd_timer sm_common cfg80211 nand input_leds joydev nand_ecc nand_bch serio_raw bch nand_ids mtd snd lpc_ich r592 memstick soundcore shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport sunrpc autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid i915 psmouse ahci libahci i2c_algo_bit firewire_ohci drm_kms_helper firewire_core sdhci_pci sdhci crc_itu_t pata_acpi syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii wmi fjes video
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917034] CPU: 1 PID: 921 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        W  OE   4.8.0-51-generic #54~16.04.1-Ubuntu
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917037] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion dv6700 Notebook PC    /30CC, BIOS F.51      02/26/2008
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917041]  0000000000000286 00000000317da17d ffff9e6d33b57928 ffffffffbdc2e293
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917048]  ffff9e6d33b57978 0000000000000000 ffff9e6d33b57968 ffffffffbd88314b
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917055]  000004c800000000 ffff9e6d34d70000 0000000000000001 0000000000000000
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917061] Call Trace:
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917071]  [<ffffffffbdc2e293>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917078]  [<ffffffffbd88314b>] __warn+0xcb/0xf0
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917087]  [<ffffffffbd8831cf>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917091]  [<ffffffffbd8c6fd5>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917106]  [<ffffffffc0055b96>] drm_wait_one_vblank+0x1b6/0x1c0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917109]  [<ffffffffbd8c7480>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917161]  [<ffffffffc0222f0f>] intel_get_load_detect_pipe+0x64f/0x670 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917196]  [<ffffffffc025f68d>] intel_tv_detect+0x13d/0x5e0 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917213]  [<ffffffffc014b02c>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes+0x27c/0x540 [drm_kms_helper]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917217]  [<ffffffffbe097ff2>] ? mutex_lock+0x12/0x30
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917236]  [<ffffffffc00612ff>] drm_mode_getconnector+0x34f/0x3a0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917240]  [<ffffffffbd8f68a6>] ? hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x1d6/0x3e0
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917254]  [<ffffffffc0053d67>] drm_ioctl+0x1e7/0x4c0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917273]  [<ffffffffc0060fb0>] ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x140/0x140 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917277]  [<ffffffffbda478c1>] do_vfs_ioctl+0xa1/0x5f0
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917279]  [<ffffffffbda47e89>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917282]  [<ffffffffbe09a8b6>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xa8
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210990.917284] ---[ end trace bb034a4fd5a47730 ]---
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102054] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102100] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 921 at /build/linux-hwe-7go7JY/linux-hwe-4.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_irq.c:1224 drm_wait_one_vblank+0x1b6/0x1c0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102102] vblank wait timed out on crtc 1
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102104] Modules linked in: nfsv3 nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss nfsv4 nfs lockd grace arc4 md4 nls_utf8 cifs fscache binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_si3054 snd_hda_codec_realtek hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq wl(POE) coretemp r852 snd_seq_device snd_timer sm_common cfg80211 nand input_leds joydev nand_ecc nand_bch serio_raw bch nand_ids mtd snd lpc_ich r592 memstick soundcore shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport sunrpc autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid i915 psmouse ahci libahci i2c_algo_bit firewire_ohci drm_kms_helper firewire_core sdhci_pci sdhci crc_itu_t pata_acpi syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii wmi fjes video
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102227] CPU: 1 PID: 921 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        W  OE   4.8.0-51-generic #54~16.04.1-Ubuntu
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102229] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion dv6700 Notebook PC    /30CC, BIOS F.51      02/26/2008
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102233]  0000000000000286 00000000317da17d ffff9e6d33b577d8 ffffffffbdc2e293
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102240]  ffff9e6d33b57828 0000000000000000 ffff9e6d33b57818 ffffffffbd88314b
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102247]  000004c833b57828 ffff9e6d34d70000 0000000000000001 0000000000000000
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102253] Call Trace:
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102263]  [<ffffffffbdc2e293>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102270]  [<ffffffffbd88314b>] __warn+0xcb/0xf0
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102275]  [<ffffffffbd8831cf>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102284]  [<ffffffffbd8c6fd5>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102299]  [<ffffffffc0055b96>] drm_wait_one_vblank+0x1b6/0x1c0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102302]  [<ffffffffbd8c7480>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102356]  [<ffffffffc021bd57>] intel_pre_plane_update+0x1a7/0x1b0 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102389]  [<ffffffffc021c3e4>] intel_atomic_commit_tail+0x154/0x10a0 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102393]  [<ffffffffbda0a921>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1a1/0x1c0
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102427]  [<ffffffffc02254c3>] ? intel_prepare_plane_fb+0xa3/0x280 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102460]  [<ffffffffc021d770>] intel_atomic_commit+0x440/0x570 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102480]  [<ffffffffc006e6c7>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x187/0x610 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102482]  [<ffffffffbd8c6fd5>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102502]  [<ffffffffc006eb87>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102535]  [<ffffffffc0222f53>] intel_release_load_detect_pipe+0x23/0x80 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102570]  [<ffffffffc025f880>] intel_tv_detect+0x330/0x5e0 [i915]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102587]  [<ffffffffc014b02c>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes+0x27c/0x540 [drm_kms_helper]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102591]  [<ffffffffbe097ff2>] ? mutex_lock+0x12/0x30
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102610]  [<ffffffffc00612ff>] drm_mode_getconnector+0x34f/0x3a0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102614]  [<ffffffffbd8f68a6>] ? hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x1d6/0x3e0
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102628]  [<ffffffffc0053d67>] drm_ioctl+0x1e7/0x4c0 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102647]  [<ffffffffc0060fb0>] ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x140/0x140 [drm]
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102650]  [<ffffffffbda478c1>] do_vfs_ioctl+0xa1/0x5f0
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102653]  [<ffffffffbda47e89>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102655]  [<ffffffffbe09a8b6>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xa8
May 13 22:02:57 bobu2 kernel: [210991.102657] ---[ end trace bb034a4fd5a47731 ]---
```

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely due to svideo on your laptop.

You could  try to disable svideo with kernel boot option like this:

```
video=SVIDEO-1:d
```

If you have grub you can edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

Then execute:

```
$ update-grub
$ reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing in your video driver. Are you running a current version of Ubuntu with all of the updates? Have you installed any special video drivers?

You've got an antique BIOS. Update to version `F.5A Rev. A` asap, found at https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-dv6700-entertainment-notebook-pc-series/3632100

And with Intel processors, you should have `intel-microcode` installed... to make sure that you have the latest processor microcode...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

Comment: It's 16.04.2 and I do keep it up to date -- no special video drivers --  I'll update the BIOS and install intel-microcode

Comment: @BobBowden do the BIOS and the intel-microcode and see if that helps. Also, does the problem occur if you log into the guest account?

Comment: intel-microcode already the latest version. The BIOS update needs windows to run and it doesn't offer the option of creating a bootable USB drive if I run it on another box. I'll try the guest account

Comment: @username keeps getting filtered out of my comment

Comment: @BobBowden because I'm the author of the answer, it assumes that you want the comment to reach me, so it doesn't need/want the @ username.

Comment: problem also occurs on the guest account -- still can't figure out how to update the BIOS. I created the diagnostics USB key, but it seems to thinks the existing BIOS supports an update facility and it does not

Comment: @BobBowden The BIOS installation instructions at the web site say to just double-click on the downloaded file and follow the instructions. This has to be done in Windows of course. Maybe you've done that, but the instructions don't match what you're seeing in the BIOS? You may have to Google your machine make/model and "BIOS update" to get help.